# Div needs to be below position absolute

Tags: html, css, position, absolute

The div "bot_wrapper" needs to sit under the top_wrapper and the ABOUTme needs to be in the 100px always. Any suggestions?

http://rileykinsella.net76.net/

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="bottom_wrapper" style="padding-left: 5px; padding-top: 5px;">
            <div class="article_wrapper">
                <div class="article_title">
                     <span>ABOUT<div class="second_word"><span>me<span></div></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Change the 5px to the correct px movement to the left/top to align where you want it to align. You can also use % value instead of px. style="padding-left:5%;" etc.

Comment: that doesn't exactly solve the problem, is there anyway to push the whole div down?

Comment: Can you be a little more descriptive as to what you're after? I can better help then... Because I am not understanding where you want what.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using position: absolute to place the bottom_wrapper however you want to. If the top wrapper will always have that height then you can do this:

```
.bottom_wrapper{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

This will align the bottom wrapper to the bottom of the page always.

As for placing the About me, i don't understand what you mean by "100px always"

Edited 1:

Change top_wrapper to:

```
.top_wrapper{
    background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    border-bottom: 6px solid #39B54A;
    height: 80%;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 602px;
}
```

Then change the bottom_wrapper to:

```
.bottom_wrapper{
    width: 960px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: like I want the text "About Me" to always be vertically aligned in that 100px

Comment: This fixes the div being at the bottom but I need more content under the about me, instead of continuing down the page, it just pushes the div up

Comment: Please see my changes and let me know if thats what you are looking for